# Add additional elements to output from DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer

I'm serializing an object (using DataContractSerializer) that have additional data, a kind of "attached properties", that's not bound to clr-properties. When serializing I only get the clr-properties of course. I'm looking for a method of both serializing and deserializing additional data without having to give up DataContractSerializer.

I have experimented with IExtensibleDataObject since it seem to be almost exactly what I'm after. But I can't seem to read or write any data from the ExtensionDataObject.

Any other method I could investigate?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is IExtensibleDataObject. See the following resources for help.

[Blog post -- WCF Extensibility – Other Serialization Extensions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/09/27/wcf-extensibility-other-serialization-extensions.aspx)

[Forward-Compatible Data Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731083.aspx)

[Data Contract Versioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731138.aspx)